# No data import working in csharp from excel file using iexceldatareader

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

> Everything is working fine it shows me message data inserted but when i check my db no data was inserted.

database name is demo having 2 fields only Id as int Primary Key, name as varchar(50)

i have a excel file with no header and 2 cols with 3 rows

```
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel Files |*.xlsx";

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
            return;

        FileStream fs = new FileStream(openFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Open);
        IExcelDataReader ed = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(fs);
        DataSet result = ed.AsDataSet();
        DataClasses1DataContext con = new DataClasses1DataContext();
        foreach (DataTable table in result.Tables)
        {
            foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
            {

                demo addTable = new demo()

                {


                      Id=Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]),
                      name=Convert.ToString(dr[1])



                };


                con.demos.InsertOnSubmit(addTable);


            }
        }

        con.SubmitChanges();
        ed.Close();
        fs.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Data Inserted ");
```

Everything is working fine it shows me message data inserted but when i check my db no data was inserted.

database name is demo having 2 fields only Id as int Primary Key, name as varchar(50)

i have a excel file with no header and 2 cols with 3 rows

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
        con.demos.Add(emp);


        con.demos.SaveChanges();
        ed.Close();
        fs.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Data Inserted ");
```